# Can I use a semicolon when linking a sentence fragment and a question?

Tags: questions, semicolons, sentence-fragments

Are there guidelines for using semi-colons in any of these kinds of circumstances (where a sentence fragment links with a question)? Please note that the words cannot be changed and dashes are prohibited as I am transcribing a conversation.

1. I was trying to leave; asking them to let me go.
2. She kept texting me; "What's up," "Want to go for a walk in the park?"
3. How did you feel about that; not having to go to work?
4. So why did you say what you did; "No," and later "I don't know"?
5. So about that cake; you made it yourself?
6. Talk about that for a moment; your tardiness, that is.
7. You bought icing; chocolate, right?
8. Is that something you regularly do; buy chocolate icing?

Comment: Only for #7. For the rest, colon or comma.

Comment: … and I would suggest “You bought icing. Chocolate, right?” or “You bought icing? Chocolate, right?” for #7.

Answer (score 2):

No, none of those semicolons work.  A semicolon is used to connect two independent clauses (i.e. things that *could* be a complete sentence) that are related to each other.  If you have only a sentence fragment on one side, a semicolon cannot be used; normally a comma or a dash would be called for there.

In several cases, you have a topic fragment and then a specifier fragment (e.g. "You bought icing; chocolate, right?").  In those cases, a colon is correct.

A colon can also be used to introduce a list.

(It's worth bearing in mind, given your note that these are transcribed conversations, that people do not always speak grammatically or in complete sentences.  However, in all of these cases, I think you can come up with something reasonable.)

I would go with the following:

> I was trying to leave, asking them to let me go.
>      She kept texting me: "What's up," "Want to go for a walk in the park?"
>      How did you feel about that, not having to go to work?
>      So why did you say what you did: "No," and later "I don't know"?
>      So about that cake—you made it yourself?
>      Talk about that for a moment—your tardiness, that is.
>      You bought icing: chocolate, right?
>      Is that something you regularly do, buy chocolate icing?

see [This "The Oatmeal" cartoon](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon) for good information about how and when to use the semicolon.

Comment: Thank you. This is the author. Regarding 5 and 6, I'm not sure if the dash would be appropriate because they are generally used to indicate false starts when people are speaking. Any other suggestions?

Comment: *Cake* followed by colon; *moment* followed by full stop and capital letter.

Comment: False starts are one use of the dash, but not the only.  However, if you don't like them, then "So about that cake: you made it yourself?" and "Talk about that for a moment... your tardiness, that is." would certainly also work.  (Or, as Andrew suggests, "Talk about that for a moment.  Your tardiness, that is."  It may be a fragment, but it's perfectly clear and is certainly a very normal way to speak.)

Comment: Thanks. One final question. Can a semicolon be used two link two complete sentences? For example:

1. I believe that's what I asked you before; you replied that you buy chocolate icing regularly, right?

2. And that's how you replied, right; you said you buy it regularly?

Comment: Yes, it can be used to link two complete sentences; I think your new #1 is fine.  However, I would not use when the first sentence is a question, as in your new #2; you lose the "question-ness" of the first sentence that way.  You're better off leaving them as 2 separate sentences:  "And that's how you replied, right?  You said you buy it regularly?"

Answer (score -3):

Semicolons are great for lists that include some complex items, ones which might not be clear if commas were used.  The items need not be clauses.  Parallelism has to be respected amongst the items.

In other words, yes, you can use semicolons: put all eight corrected items in a list separated by the semicolons.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with lists. Please reread it.

Comment: Yes, Matt, please re-read it.  He asks if he can use a semicolon in a following list.  He can, as I explained.

Comment: No he does not. He asks if a semicolong can be used in the circumstances that he lists. That is not the same thing.