# How can I make this sentence read better?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, flow

I'm writing a bio for my website. I have a section where I talk about why I am interested in computer programming. When I read it to myself, it sounds great (because I know where to put the pauses in my head) but I'm not sure how well it reads to someone who isn't me. Can anyone give some input? I think it needs a semi colon somewhere or something.

> At the core of my passion however, is the knowledge that with enough
>   work, programming is a medium that can turn thoughts and ideas into
>   actual value, real products that can demonstrate influence over the
>   malleable world we let them loose in.

Comment: "and ideas into actual value, real products that can demonstrate" -- there seems to be a disconnect there.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah that's where I felt the disconnect as well, but my grammar is abysmal. So, I wasn't sure what to put there besides a period.

Comment: Remember, there's no law saying that you can't use more than one sentence.  Often that's the best solution to awkward, run-on sentences.

Comment: ... *that can turn thoughts and ideas into real products with actual value that can assert influence over the malleable world we let them loose in.*  But I really think that the statement becomes too highfalutin and pretentious for its own good starting with "malleable world..."

Comment: @Jim isn't highfalutin just a synonym for pretentious? Why'd you use both? Was it to show off your intelligence?

Comment: I just wrote what sounded right...

Comment: @Jim Sorry that was my ego speaking. Forgive me lol.     Also, I just re-read your comment. I didn't even realize you were suggesting an alternative. I thought you were just quoting my original word choice. Thanks for the contribution and again, I apologize.

Comment: I don't think "real products with actual value" is actually the intent--it sounds more to me like real products _are_ the actual value.

Comment: @Yee-Lum- Yeah, but I think a lot of products out there have no real value.

Comment: also, I'd like to point out that this sentence is embedded in a paragraph. It doesn't stand well on its own, but I feel it flows well with the overall "vibe" of the paragraph it's embedded in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gut instinct is right, because as it is, the sentence is a run-on and not quite grammatically correct. So it won't read properly to outside readers. You can easily fix it with some punctuation.

> At the core of my passion, however, is the knowledge that with enough
>   work, programming is a medium that can turn thoughts and ideas into
>   actual value: real products that can demonstrate influence over the
>   malleable world we let them loose in.

That is, a comma after "passion", and something other than a comma after "value"--an em-dash would also work. You can also always just split it into two smaller sentences.

Answer (score 0):

@Yee-Lum it is more butchered than you think. Plus a colon does not fit there; a semicolon as just used here would be more appropriate.

"At the core of my passion however, is the knowledge that with enough work, programming is a medium that can turn thoughts and ideas into actual value, real products that can demonstrate influence over the malleable world we let them loose in."

When your second comma is employed after the word, "work," your sentence ceases to make sense when followed by "programming is -." 
This would make more sene (note how I removed the word, "that" after, "medium"):

At the core of my passion however, is the knowledge that with enough work, programming [AS] a medium can turn thoughts and ideas into . . .

Now I think if you switched your wording a little bit, your message would sound much stronger. Instead of turning thoughts into value at first, use products instead, then mention value secondly. Like this:

"At the core of my passion however, is the knowledge that with enough work, programming as a medium can turn thoughts and ideas into tangible products with real value; creations that can demonstrate influence over the malleable world we let them loose in."

How does that look to you?

Comment: .......I like it!

Comment: You might like it, but this answer is unfortunately wrong. The part of a sentence that follows a semicolon cannot be an incomplete sentence, and "creations that can demonstrate influence over the malleable world we let them loose in" is not a full sentence because it doesn't actually have a verb. "...that can demonstrate..." is a descriptive phrase for "creations", and not a verb phrase. And you do still need a comma after "passion".

Comment: The wording is up to you, and there's always license (in informal writing like a website bio) to not adhere _completely_ strictly to grammar rules if you feel that it benefits your writing, but a colon is the more grammatically correct punctuation for your original sentence.

Comment: Yee-Lum, you are so wrong I cannot even begin to pluck at the fallacies you are asserting.

Comment: Maybe you could do me the favor of trying to pluck so both @LukeP and I can learn from you?

Comment: "Can I use a semicolon when linking a fragment?" "No. A semicolon is used to connect two independent clauses (i.e. things that could be a complete sentence) that are related to each other." http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181499/can-i-use-a-semicolon-when-linking-a-sentence-fragment-and-a-question